# What is a Thanos Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Thanos Word™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Thanos }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  BLACK }&\text{ WHITE }\\ \hline
\text{  BLINDSIDE }&\text{ IMPACT }\\ \hline
\text{  DISCOMBOBULATED }&\text{ AWARE }\\ \hline
\text{  FLIBBERTIGIBBET }&\text{ THINGAMAJIG }\\ \hline
\text{  FLOTSAM }&\text{ DEBRIS }\\ \hline
\text{  FOOLHARDY }&\text{ SAVVY }\\ \hline
\text{  INTERLOPER }&\text{ GUEST }\\ \hline
\text{  MASTERMIND }&\text{ NOVICE }\\ \hline
\text{  NIGER }&\text{ NIGERIA }\\ \hline
\text{  WHOOP }&\text{ BOO }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Thanos Words™,Not Thanos Words™
BLACK, WHITE
BLINDSIDE, IMPACT
DISCOMBOBULATED, AWARE
FLIBBERTIGIBBET, THINGAMAJIG
FLOTSAM, DEBRIS 
FOOLHARDY, SAVVY 
INTERLOPER, GUEST 
MASTERMIND, NOVICE 
NIGER, NIGERIA
WHOOP, BOO
```

Hint 1:

> [image: Hint 1]

Comment: [THANOS WORD. THANOS WORD.](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/thanos-car) (Possible NSFW warning)

Comment: May be cool to golf.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A **Thanos Word** is:

> **Perfectly balanced**
>
>  That is, take the left side and the right side of a word, and compute the position in the alphabet:
>
> ```
>  FLIBBERTIGIBBET ->
>  F: 6, L: 12, I: 9, B: 2, B: 2, E: 5, R: 18, T: 20, I: 9, G: 7, I: 9, B: 2, B: 2, E: 5, T: 20
> ```
>
> Then, split the word into two halves (excluding center character if odd length), and take the sums of the values:
>
> ```
>  FLIBBER (_) IGIBBET
>  FLIBBER = 6 + 12 + 9 + 2 + 2 + 5 + 18 = 54
>  IGIBBET = 9 + 7 + 9 + 2 + 2 + 5 + 20 = 54
> ```
>
> If the sums are equal, it's a Thanos Word

Comment: Perfect! Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: ..."like all things should be" -Thanos